# What's the gnu-netcat's '-z' equivalent option in nmap-ncat?

Tags: netcat, nmap

I check for a listening port on a service prior to running a script using this :

```
until nc -z $HOST $PORT
do
  echo "waiting for service to be available..."
  sleep 0.5
done

exec "/my/script"
```

It used to work with gnu-netcat, but now, I've upgraded the Linux distribution, and it uses nmap-ncat for the `/usr/bin/nc` command.

I'd like to know an equivalent solution to use with `nmap-ncat` package.

Comment: Same question recently asked and answered on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/q/788934/112426

Answer (score 13):

`--send-only </dev/null` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My challenge is that I just wanted to check connectivity via a "for" loop and exit (which -z provides) but -z is not an option in my version of CentOS, so this works for my needs:

nc -vi 2 $h $p
...
-v, --verbose              Set verbosity level (can be used several times)
-i, --idle-timeout   Idle read/write timeout
...
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to $h:$p.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (2000 ms).
...